# Couldn't take value from web.config from other project

Tags: c#, web-config

I have added web.Config file in my main project (where exe file resides), I need to access a value from this web.cofig file from other project.

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="Name" value="TestProject" />
</appSettings>`
```

I am taking value using WebConfigurationManger as follows,

```cs
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"]
```

But it always returns null. What I am missing here ?

Comment: web.config file is project specific. so you can access it on other project..

Comment: I don't understand how you can say "web.config" and "exe" in the same sentence. To my knowledge they have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to create project Dependency base on your requirement. then you can access your parent project web.config property.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"]
```